I facing this type error anybody give some solutions for this error

Usr/bin/env/: bad interpreter:no such file or directory

please post the text, not a picture of text

It looks like the shebang (first line) of your my_first_node.py has usr/bin/env/ python as the interpreter. It should be /usr/bin/env python.
